# java.lang.classcastexception- spring, rest

Tags: java, spring, rest

My class Rest doesn't invoke my other class

```
@CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
public class PhoneRest {
    
    @Autowired
    private TradePhoneService service;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:4200","http://localhost:8081"})
    @PostMapping(value = "/listarRamaisDiponiveis", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity <List<TpbPrvtRecPhoneExtVO>> listarRamaisDiponiveis() {
        List<TpbPrvtRecPhoneExtVO> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        try {

            list =service.listarRamaisDiponiveis(); // here java.lang.classcastexception
```

About interface TradePhoneService:

```
public interface TradePhoneService {
    public List<TpbPrvtRecPhoneExtVO> listarRamaisDiponiveis();
```

About class TpbPrvtRecPhoneExtVO:

```
public class TpbPrvtRecPhoneExtVO extends BaseVO implements Serializable{
```

And about class TradePhoneServiceImpl that implements TradePhoneService:

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn=Exception.class)
@Service
public class TradePhoneServiceImpl implements TradePhoneService {
    @Autowired
    private TradePhoneDAO dao;

    public List<TpbPrvtRecPhoneExtVO> listarRamaisDiponiveis() {
        return listBeansToVos(dao.listarRamaisDiponiveis());
    }
```

Where is the problem?

Thanks
Marcos Vizine

Comment: Could you add the full stacktrace for the classcastexception?

Comment: Why do you think its not calling the implementation class?  Is there a stack trace or other error?